# 表記を統一してほしい :トップ バーのレヴュー リンクをクリックしてから

Tags: バグ, 完了, 日本語, ヘルプ, 権限

https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools
の次の文:

> トップ バーのレヴュー リンクをクリックしてから、

トップバーにはレヴューと書かれていません。レビューだと思います。

Comment: 個人的には勿論レビューの方が見慣れていて良いとは思いますが、間違っているわけでもなさそうです…でも表記揺れしているので統一した方がいいですね。[参考](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%AC%E3%83%B4%E3%83%A5%E3%83%BC)

Comment: レヴューも確かに間違ってません。それでも、表記を統一した方がいいです。

Comment: 今の質問文なら分かり良いです。表記揺れは統一した方がいいのは私も同意します。